# How to make one div higher than the other two

Tags: html, css

I have this CSS code:

```
    #naviga {
text-align:center;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

#nav {
display:inline;
  padding-top: 0px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 #ffffff;
  -webkit-transition: all 250ms linear;
  -moz-transition: all 250ms linear;
  -ms-transition: all 250ms linear;
  -o-transition: all 250ms linear;
  transition: all 250ms linear;
}

#nav a {
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 #ffffff;
  -webkit-transition: all 250ms linear;
  -moz-transition: all 250ms linear;
  -ms-transition: all 250ms linear;
  -o-transition: all 250ms linear;
  transition: all 250ms linear;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  margin-left: 20px;

}

#nav a:hover {
  -webkit-box-shadow: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 0 0 #fff;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

#loggo {
display:inline;
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/qhrrawQ.png);
height: 50px;
width: 55px;
margin-left: 20px;
}
```

...and this HTML code:

```
<div id="naviga">
<div id="nav"><a href="">uno</a> <a href="">due</a> <a href="">tre</a></div>
<div id="loggo"></div> 
<div id="nav"><a href="">quattro</a> <a href="">cinque</a> <a href="">sei</a></div> 
</div>
</div>
```

This is what comes out:

[image: current]

And this is what I would like it to come out like:

[image: intended]

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

You are using `display:inline` although I prefer `inline-block` here.

You need to set the `vertical-align` to `middle` as the default is `baseline`.

**Note**: You were using the same ID (#) more than once which is invalid. So I switched them to classes instead.

```css
   .naviga {
     text-align: center;
     padding-top: 20px;
   }
   .nav {
     display: inline-block;
     vertical-align: middle;
     padding-top: 0px;
     color: blue;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     text-decoration: none;
   }
   .nav a {
     padding-bottom: 3px;
     letter-spacing: 1px;
     margin-left: 20px;
   }
   .loggo {
     display: inline-block;
     vertical-align: middle;
     background: red;
     height: 50px;
     width: 55px;
     margin-left: 20px;
   }
```

```html
<div class="naviga">
  <div class="nav"><a href="">uno</a>  <a href="">due</a>  <a href="">tre</a>
  </div>
  <div class="loggo"></div>
  <div class="nav"><a href="">quattro</a>  <a href="">cinque</a>  <a href="">sei</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `vertical-align: middle` to the classes

[Read more about align here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273338/how-to-vertically-align-an-image-inside-div)

Answer (score 0):

You can't add a height to inline elements. Just change your list items to `display:block;` (or `inline-block`) and then specify a height equal to the logo height like this:

```
#nav a{
    display: block;
    line-height: 50px;
    float:left;
    background: none;
    margin: 0px 10px;
}
```

Here's a jsfiddle with above codes: http://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL32/65sf2f66/44/